# Process model 7 with nonsignificant conditional indirect effects

Tags: regression, interaction, spss, mediation

I have one categorical IV, one categorical moderator, and a continuous M and Y. I runs a moderated mediation model 7 based on proposed model of my study. The result show that there is a significant index of moderated mediation, but one of the conditional indirect effects are nonsignificant. How should I interpret that? Can I still claim that there is a moderated mediation effects exists for that model?[image]